# Cordova App for Windows 10 stuck on Splash screen at launch behind a proxy

Tags: cordova, uwp, proxy, crash

I have a Cordova app working fine on multiple devices that are connected to internet.

**Behavior Observed:**

But when I deploy the app on our dev env VM, it just freezes on splash screen. The one peculiar thing I noticed is that every time I launch a browser, it asks me to login to the proxy server. This is because the proxy uses my production credentials to authenticate. The credentials are saved in the browser, I just have to click on OK. I feel that the app is unable to launch as the web view is waiting for a proxy login prompt to be actioned, which is obviously invisible at launch time. The app just sits there until it is closed.

Also, when I run the app in debug mode using VS2017, the index.html file is loaded with just the head tag, **no body tag**.

All libraries and scripts are referenced locally in the head tab as the app is meant to work offline as well. Sample of head section below.

**Configuration:**

**index.html**

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/datepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/easyautocomplete/easy-autocomplete.css">
    <link href="scripts/growl/jquery.growl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="scripts/jquery-confirm/jquery-confirm.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/SHMOStyles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ripple.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fastclick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mapapi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/hammer.min.js"></script>
```

I use some plugins in config.xml, but there is no problem with any of them as I run them in production env or any device connected straight to the internet. In production, it uses same credentials for computer logon and proxy, so I do not get the login prompt like I do in Dev env.

**config.xml**

```
<vs:platformSpecificValues>
    <vs:platformSpecificWidget platformName="windows" id="SIMSMobileV0" />
  </vs:platformSpecificValues>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fastclick" spec="~1.0.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="~2.0.19" />
  <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~2.3.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.4.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~2.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~2.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~5.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~6.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-zeep" spec="~0.0.4" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~6.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~4.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-insomnia" spec="~4.3.0" />
```

Things I tried:

1. Override proxy settings on the windows 10 VM, still leads to prompt coming up
2. Save credentials in Windows/Generic credentials for proxy host, no luck
3. Added proxy configuration to npm, git, gradle, etc. Did not work

The question is, how to resolve this situation so:

1. the proxy login prompt appears in the app? I did some research, it looks like cordova apps dont support this. But, keen to see if this can be done.
2. Add a module to the app to manage this behavior if it detects no connectivity
3. Somehow setup a persistent proxy globally without installing any software or without connecting to a VPN

If you have any other suggestions / solutions, they are most welcome. Any help can be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DaveAlden Are you able to help

Answer (score 1):

Upon further analysis with network monitor, I could see traffic going to the google fonts api. So, the issue was that the page header had a line to connect to google api for fonts. This was looking for an internet connection and proxy would challenge for credentials with `HTTP 407`.

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

After commenting out this line, the app is now able to launch successfully. Hopefully it helps other people as well.